# ASP.NET Web Forms Incorrect Values Being Displayed/Saved

Tags: asp.net, caching, ssl

Recently, we added SSL to an application I support and it broke a "Print" button with issues similar to what is described [here](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/8_2005_1_0_0_35695/Cacheability-issue-with-IE.htm).

Without the SSL, the button would produce a PDF report with Open and Save prompts.  Once SSL was implemented and we made changes to the MasterPage HTTP Cacheability, the Print button worked again.

Our master page had the following code in the Page_Load:

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now;
    Response.Expires = 0;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
}
```

and it was changed/implemented as:

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Expires = -1;
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

The print button Click event has the following code:

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        ClearMessage();

        BusinessObject _obj = GetBusinessObject();

        Id = _obj.BusinessObjectId;
        string strId = Id.ToString();
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string mimetype = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;

        ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer() {
            ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
        };
        viewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/ReportPath/ReportFile";

        ReportParameterCollection objParams = new ReportParameterCollection();
        objParams.Add(new ReportParameter("ObjId", strId));

        viewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(objParams);

        byte[] bytes = viewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimetype, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimetype;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + GetBusinessObject().ObjNumber + " Object Summary." + extension);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ClearMessage();
        ErrorEmail("AppError", "btnPrint_Click", ex);
    }
}
```

I thought everything was great but it looks like it may have caused even more problems because now I have reports of incorrect data being displayed between pages (information from one record being displayed for another).

The cacheability changes were the only thing that changed in the code when the SSL was implemented and we have not had any reports of this happening before (the application has been live for over a year now).  Furthermore, I had my backup programmer revert the changes in our production branch code, publish to our staging server, and try to replicate the issue...they could not.

### UPDATE

I made the following change to the sitewide web.config and the problem seems to have disappeared.  Can anyone explain why this worked but the code did not?

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
<system.webServer>
```

### UPDATE

Setting
`<clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />` did not fix the issue and we were still experiencing the problem intermittently.  See accepted answer as solution that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the issue was really with the SSL certs being installed improperly.  The basic setup is we have a load balancer and SSL certs terminating on 2 web servers.

The incorrect values were being displayed/saved because the load balancer could not read the cookie (since it was encrypted) to determine which server to direct to and since we use session variables, it would not clear the session variables properly.

Our stop-gap fix was to switch the routing decision to IP based.  As you can imagine, this causes all users behind one firewall to direct to the same server and defeats the purpose of the load balancer.

Our permanent solution is to put a 3rd SSL cert on the load balancer, decrypt the cookie to determine which server to direct to, encrypt the data once more and then send it off to the server.

Hopefully this helps someone else that runs into the same problem.